# Which software can I use to extract an audio track from a video?

Tags: sound, video

I used VirtualDubMod on Windows to pull off the sound from a video file. What software could do the same on Ubuntu? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WinFF. A simple GUI to FFmpeg. Winff is in Ubuntu's repositories. Do `sudo apt-get install winff` to install it.

[image: WinFF]

Answer (score 9):

Command line:

```
ffmpeg -i input_file.flv -vn output_file.mp3
ffmpeg -i input_file.mov -vn output_file.mp3
ffmpeg -i input_file.avi -vn output_file.mp3
```

If ffmpeg is not installed ...

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

and of course you need the audiocodecs required to play the video/audiofiles.

Comment: I found a easier way, it can be done by using avidemux, in "audio" section by pressing "save" you can extract sound from video file. I am sorry, I was too fast with questions, all I needed just a little bit "google". It's not so hard with ubuntu :)

Comment: command line is always better but you can always remove the accepted answer and make your own if you want.

Comment: Ubuntu now uses the `avconv` fork by default instead of original `ffmpeg`, but the option syntax stays the same. For example: `sudo apt-get install libav-tools; avconv -i input_file.mov output_file.mp3`.

Answer (score 2):

Soundconverter, a lightweight simple app for converting audio files and can also take video as input.  `sudo apt-get install soundconverter`